# Inject a module in MEAN.io module

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I'd like to integrate ui-rangeSlider in a app based on MEAN.io framework.
But I think the problem is the same for any module.

When I add the parameter in the function

`angular.module('mean', ['ui-rangeSlider']).controller('PreferencesController', ['$scope', 'Global',`

I added the required static ressources in the app.js :

`Preferences.aggregateAsset('js', 'angular.rangeSlider.js');`

I get an error 
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mean due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider`

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you see this? [How to implement jQuery range slider in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113195/how-to-implement-jquery-range-slider-in-angularjs)

I think you need to pass $stateProvider to your  module. Without seeing more code I am not sure, I think it is not finding $stateProvider and is not an error related to the range slider script.